# Invalid foreign key column name error ef Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

im trying to create API with related entities in EF Core. I don't understand why It throwing this error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'AuthorId'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IAsyncEnumerableOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TAsyncEnumerable value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IAsyncEnumerableOfTConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TAsyncEnumerable value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
ClientConnectionId:a2b92e1b-ed00-4050-b7ff-23ed1f0fa3a3
Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:7079
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.30.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Postman-Token: 3d4c8593-da6e-4682-95c5-5aa54dd7b7df
```

Models:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace LibraryAPI.Resources
{
    // Book model
    public class Book
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
        public Author Author { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
        public float Rating { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(13)")]
        public int ISBN { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "Datetime2")]
        public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }


    }
    public class BookDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public float Rating { get; set; }
        public int ISBN { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LibraryAPI.Resources
{
    // Author model
    public class Author 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")] 
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
        public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
        [Column(TypeName = "Datetime2")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
        }
        [Column(TypeName = "Datetime2")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; } 
        [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Context:

```
namespace LibraryAPI.Resources;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public LibraryContext(DbContextOptions<LibraryContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
             .Entity<Author>()
             .Property(e => e.Gender)
             .HasConversion<GenderToNumericCoverter>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Author)
            .WithMany(b => b.Books);
            
    }
    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Properties<DateOnly>()
            .HaveConversion<DateOnlyConverter>()
            .HaveColumnType("Datetime2");
    }

    public DbSet<Author> Author { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; } = null!;
    //public DbSet<BookAuthor> BookAuthor { get; set; }
}
```

Controllers:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using LibraryAPI.Resources;
using System.Web.Http.Description;

namespace LibraryAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BooksController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly LibraryContext _context;

        public BooksController(LibraryContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Books
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>>> GetBooks()
        {
            var books = from b in _context.Book.Include(b => b.Author)
                        select new BookDto()
                        {
                            Id = b.Id,
                            Title = b.Title,
                            Description = b.Description,
                            AuthorName = b.Author.FullName,
                            Rating = b.Rating,
                            ISBN = b.ISBN,
                            PublicationDate = b.PublicationDate
                        };

                        

            return Ok(books);
        }

        //GET: api/BooksByAuthor/[Authorname]
        [ResponseType(typeof(BookDto))]
        [HttpGet("{AuthorName}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooksByAuthor(string AuthorName)
        {
            var books = from b in _context.Book.Include(b => b.Author)
                        where b.Author.FullName == AuthorName
                        select new BookDto()
                        {
                            Id = b.Id,
                            Title = b.Title,
                            Description = b.Description,
                            AuthorName = b.Author.FullName,
                            Rating = b.Rating,
                            ISBN = b.ISBN,
                            PublicationDate = b.PublicationDate
                        };
            if (books == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            return Ok(books);
        }

        // GET: api/Books/[Title]
        [ResponseType(typeof(BookDto))]
        [HttpGet("{Title}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> GetBookByTitle(string title)
        {
            var books = from b in _context.Book.Include(b => b.Author)
                        where b.Title == title
                        select new BookDto()
                        {
                            Id = b.Id,
                            Title = b.Title,
                            Description = b.Description,
                            AuthorName = b.Author.FullName,
                            Rating = b.Rating,
                            ISBN = b.ISBN,
                            PublicationDate = b.PublicationDate
                        };
            if (books == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            return Ok(books);
        }



        // PUT: api/Books/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutBook(int id, Book book)
        {
            if (id != book.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BookExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Ok(book);
        }

        // POST: api/Books
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> PostBook(Book book)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            _context.Book.Add(book);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            _context.Entry(book).Reference(b => b.Author).Load();

            var dto = new BookDto()
            {
                Id = book.Id,
                Title = book.Title,
                Description = book.Description,
                AuthorName = book.Author.FullName,
                Rating = book.Rating,
                ISBN = book.ISBN,
                PublicationDate = book.PublicationDate
            };
            return CreatedAtAction("GetBook", new { id = book.Id }, book);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Books/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteBook(int id)
        {
            var book = await _context.Book.FindAsync(id);
            if (book == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Book.Remove(book);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();
        }

        private bool BookExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Book.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using LibraryAPI.Resources;

namespace LibraryAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthorsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly LibraryContext _context;

        public AuthorsController(LibraryContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Authors
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Author>>> GetAuthors()
        {

            return await _context.Author.Include("Book").ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Author/[FullName]
        [HttpGet("{FullName}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Author>>> GetAuthorByName(string FullName)
        {
            var author = await _context.Author.FindAsync(FullName);

            if (author == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(author);
        }

        // GET: api/Authors/[id]
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Author>> GetAuthor(int id)
        {
            var author = await _context.Author.FindAsync(id);

            if (author == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return author;
        }

        // PUT: api/Authors/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutAuthor(int id, Author author)
        {
            if (id != author.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(author).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!AuthorExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Authors
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Author>> PostAuthor(Author author)
        {
            _context.Author.Add(author);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetAuthor", new { id = author.Id }, author);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Authors/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAuthor(int id)
        {
            var author = await _context.Author.FindAsync(id);
            if (author == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Author.Remove(author);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool AuthorExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Author.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using LibraryAPI;
using LibraryAPI.Resources;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
}); ;
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyConverterJSON()));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LibraryDB")));
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I tried adding Foreign key attribute but it didn't change anything. I checked relationship configuration but it seems fine. Tried inverse property and still nothing.

I will glady take any other tips how to improve this code :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change it before uploading. That was just for testing things out. I have it properly applied and still doesn't work. Edited code to state its now.

Comment: [ForeignKey("AuthorId")] implies that there is a field called "AuthorID" that matches the primary key of Author.  So you'd want to add that.  For instance: public int? AuthorID { get; set; }  in Book.  When you create a Book you set the AuthorID to the existing Author, or if it doesn't exist yet, create it and use the created Author record's ID.

Comment: @pcalkins so I should also change postbook method to check for the author id and set it or create new author? This dbo entity makes any sense here?

Comment: Seems like it depends on how the interface takes a new book.  (Is Author a pulldown populated with existing authors? a combo-box?)  But seems like you'd be checking Authors for the name first... (name is exclusive?) The "BookDto" class doesn't seem necessary to me...   on a side note I don't use the builder methods... I use a model-first where DB is defined by POCOs and EF takes care of building/maintaining the DB end.  So the DB first approach may be a little different regarding IDs/foreign keys.